# Browser can't reach destinations outside proxy

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-explorer

I have a couple of new touchscreen machines (Acer Veriton V3631G) at a school which run Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9.  For some reason Internet Explorer can only reach destinations inside the intranet.  Anything outside that (ie. google.com) causes the familiar "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".  Pinging "www.google.com" does however work and returns packets.  Internet Options are automatically set to retrieve the PAC file via DNS and cannot be changed by users.

Due to the machines being used by disabled students we have it set to login automatically via Registry entries.  The problem doesn't appear to be related to the user profile though.  The same problem occurs using my administrator account.

The machine has a wireless device (Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222).  We have also tried the LAN adapter with the Wifi disabled with intermittent success (got google search page to appear once).

Internet Explorer is the only browser installed on the site.  I have physically moved this machine to a different network switch (our Tech Room) and the same problem occurs.

Is there any way to establish whether Internet Explorer actually has correct PAC file and is resolving to the correct destinations?  What else can I do to isolate the problem?

EDIT:

I have captured a couple of sessions with Wireshark.  On my own machine Internet Explorer performs an HTTP GET request for the pac file it performs as expected.  On the problem machine there is no request for the pac file.  Why could this be happening?  A problem with DNS maybe?

Comment: Edited my answer for your new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Wireshark and/or Fiddler to actually see the traffic on or closer to the wire.

/Edit  - now that you see the PAC file isn't even being requested, find out why. Do you have confirmation that the GPO has been applied to the user's session on the machine in question? If it's a problem with DNS, you would at least see a request going out, which you say you're not. Why do you think it's a DNS problem?

Also - don't make one question an iterative troubleshooting platform. You solved the question you asked. It brought up another problem, so make that a new question.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you would look for?

Comment: For one thing, you'll be able to determine if you're getting the PAC file or not. Also, test the PAC file using an online parser to make sure you didn't forget to close a bracket, or similar.

Comment: You are right on the money!  The problem machine doesn't appear to be retrieving the pac file!

Comment: Great, glad to hear you found the problem! (Don't forget to mark an accepted answer; it's how the site works.)